# ERROR: cannot open source file x11\xlib.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, gesture

I'm using openCV 2.4.8 and visual studio Express 2012. I included all the Environmental variable PATH and Additional library etc.For hand gesture recognize sample code i used from [here](https://github.com/jujojujo2003/OpenCVHandGuesture/blob/master/main.cpp).
when I run the code I get this error:

`ERROR: cannot open source file x11\xlib.h`

.I tried in google but i can't able to get a proper solution.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
```

Comment: X11 stuff is very Unixy, and I understand you are on Windows. Are you sure you have X11-dev environment?

Comment: I'm using windows. X11-dev environment means?

Comment: libX11 and friends. See http://x.cygwin.com/ for starters.

Answer (score 0):

you just can't use that code on windows.

while opencv itself is pretty portable, above code is clearly not.

(instead of using cv::imshow() etc,  jujojujo2003 was using native Xwindow calls to pirate the cursor.)